# How to find out (today, this week, this month, this year) popular repositories on Github as if Github trending ?

Tags: github, github-api

On Github Trending (https://github.com/trending), I find out (today, this week, this month) popular repositories....The result is good....

I tried to obtain same results using Github Search API.....The API is as follows:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1&s=stars&order=desc

This method returns current popular repositories in JASON......But I could not find out  popular repositories during designated (e.g. this week, this month, this year, etc) period with this method...

There are Github API parameters related to period ??

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the repository search API, you can specify `created` or `pushed` parameters to return repositories in a certain time period. See [the API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories), specifically the [searching repositories documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-when-a-repository-was-created-or-last-updated).

Comment: I try on it !!  Thanks again :-)